# How to name RSpec 'context' statement "arguments"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpect 2 (BTW: with 'factory_girl_rails', 'capybara' and 'guard-rspec' gems). I would like to know how I should name `context` statement *arguments* in order to build consistent and maintainable spec file codes.

I mean, if in a `rspec.rb` file I have a code like the following

```
describe User do
  context "Argument"
    ...
    context "Argument nested"
      ...
    end
      context "Argument nested 1"
        ...
          context "Argument nested ..."
            ...
          end
      end
  end
end
```

maybe, for convenience, I may state "Argument nested < n >" context names in a way so to create "understandable patterns" in order to have\gain some "design advantages" (eg: those related to application code readability, developer productivity, ...). But, **how to do that** (maybe following a "Ruby on Rails Way to do things"...)**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the style Jared recommends here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/10/21/rspec-best-practices/